# How to choose fields for auditing with Hibernate Envers?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I'm using Hibernate Envers in Spring Boot application with Spring Data. For example, I have a base class

```
@MappedSuperclass
class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    // some base fields
    // getter and setter
}
```

And class

```
@Entity
class Entity extends BaseEntity {
    // some fields
    // getters and setters
}
```

**I need to audit only actions that were done and the timestamp of them**. For example, when I create new Entity or update existing Entity object, I want auditing table to contain the following information: **id of entity, time of action, type action**.
If I will just add @Audited to Entity class then all fields of Entity will be audited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude some fields from being audited by using the [@NotAudited](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/NotAudited.html) annotation like this ...

```
@Audited
@Entity
class User {
  ...
  @NotAudited
  private String phoneNumber;
}
```

**EDIT:** You can control the schema of the audit table and decide exactly what info to log for each revision by creating a custom revision entity like [this](https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-envers-with-custom-revision-entity)

In essence you define a `CustomRevisionEntity` and `CustomRevisionLister`

Comment: Yes, but my entities have more then 15 fields and hang @NotAudited for all fields doesn't seem a good decision

Comment: You can them put @Audited only on the fields/methods you want to audit and not the entire class. See here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/Audited.html

Comment: Thanks. But in my case I don't need to audit any fields. I need to track only time and type of all changes.

Comment: Please see post edit